# Symbolically stored mathematical values

Tags: java

I am making a program in Java which handles irrational numbers (such as square roots) and complex numbers. I was trying to make the program with numeric math, but there are rounding errors. Is there a way to do this that allows storing values symbolically - such as using `sqrt(2)i` and doesn't evaluate (ie. stores values in such a way that no rounding will be done that has these properties):

- I do not need to evaluate mathematical equations, just expressions with no variables
- I don't want Operator Overloading
- Must have fractions, complex numbers, Matricies and roots/powers
- Preferably easy to use
- Will simplify expressions when it can
- Get numeric value from the expression

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: "I don't want Operator Overloading" — Good, because Java doesn't support operator overloading. (Only the String class does have an overload of the `+` operator, to ease string concatenation.)

Comment: Delaying evaluation will not get you a higher precision.

Comment: @MCEmperor There are JavaC hacks though, like java-oo

Comment: @p.streef if the program reads sqrt(2)^2, it will evaluate as 2, but in java, it elvaluates as 1.99999998

Comment: that is not delaying evaluation, that is using a totally different method of evaluation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Java [Symja project](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) you can solve your problem with the following steps:

```
import org.matheclipse.core.eval.ExprEvaluator;
import org.matheclipse.core.expression.F;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.SyntaxError;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.math.MathException;

public class SymbolicSO43739728 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExprEvaluator util = new ExprEvaluator();
            // (3/4)*(4/3)*Sqrt(2)*I
            IExpr formula = F.Times(F.QQ(3, 4), F.QQ(4, 3), F.Sqrt(F.ZZ(2)), F.CI);

            // symbolic evaluation
            IExpr result = util.evaluate(formula);
            // print: I*Sqrt(2)
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            // numerical evaluations
            result = util.evaluate(F.N(formula));
            // I*1.4142135623730951
            System.out.println(result.toString());

        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            // catch Symja parser errors here
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MathException me) {
            // catch Symja math errors here
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final StackOverflowError soe) {
            System.out.println(soe.getMessage());
        } catch (final OutOfMemoryError oome) {
            System.out.println(oome.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify and store these expressions in a script language that Java supports - javascript, ruby, python, groovy, etc. I'm pretty sure you can find some neat math libraries in, say, python that can evaluate the more advanced math features you mentioned.